# How to embed an url in an e-mail using MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Do not answer to set to YES the property of the MFMailComposeViewController, and then simply write the html link through Link

It simply does NOT work. Try it.

Thank you.

Luca

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058447/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-how-do-i-embed-a-clickable-url-link-into-the-email

Look at XJones's answer