# Hyperlink in email body does not working in iphone

Tags: iphone, html, email, html-email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I  have used following code to display hyper link in email body.But it only shows text in message body.when i click  on it.Nothing happens.

```
-(IBAction)emailToFriend:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"E-Mail...");
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];



    [controller setMessageBody:@"<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">http://www.google.com</a>" isHTML:YES]; 

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];

}
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong here?I checked the question [MFMailComposeViewController : how do I embed a clickable URL link into the email message body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058447/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-how-do-i-embed-a-clickable-url-link-into-the-email.But) it did not help me

Comment: I think the textView disable the link checker when it's in editable mode. Have you checked if the incoming mail hasn't the link?

Comment: Yes,Incoming mail contains the link.Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before sending the link, it is not clickable. It's just plain text. However, after sending the email, the receiver will be able to click the link (the email program makes it clickable).