# url link is not getting sent from email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my iphone application, in MFMailComposer, I m adding an attachment. that attachment as a url link.in that link there is a pdf file. When I click send the url link is not sent to destination mail address.

I am using this code

```
  -(void)sendMail
 {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailView= [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailView.mailComposeDelegate=self;
    [mailView setSubject:titleString];
    NSArray  *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:emailString, nil];
    [mailView setToRecipients:array];
    NSData *textData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.fileString];
    [mailView addAttachmentData:textData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:self.fileString];

    [mailView setMessageBody:self.templatetextstring isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: paste your code of what you have tried

Comment: If you are adding a link, why not put it into the body of the email?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MFMailComposeViewController : how do I embed a clickable URL link into the email message body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058447/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-how-do-i-embed-a-clickable-url-link-into-the-email)

Comment: As comments and answers suggest, we're not clear as to whether your intent was to attach the PDF in your email (i.e. it's a file URL on the sender's device) or whether the file is on a server, and you simply wanted to to compose an email that has a URL link for it. Can you clarify?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Do you want a link in mail and on that link you want to open pdf attached in your mail?

Comment: Your adding attachmentData for plain text you should not me doing this. What is the file extension for `self.fileString`? That is what should be in `mimeType`. Also why you adding the `self.fileString' as the AttachmentData as well as the fileName?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
[controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><font size=\"2\" face=\"Helvetica\"><a href=%@></br>%@</br></a></br></font></p>",link,@"Google"] isHTML:YES];
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question probably whether you want to attach a pdf document or whether you just want to add a link to a pdf document so I will answer both. Here is the code I use to attach pdf data onto an email

```
- (void)emailFile
{
    if(![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        UIAlertView *cantSend = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Device not configured to send email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
       [cantSend show];
    } else {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailView setSubject:@"PDF Attached to email"];

        // Adding an actual PDF document to the email.
        [mailView addAttachmentData:(__bridge NSData *)myPDFData mimeType:@"pdf" fileName:@"AttachedPDFDocument"];

        [mailView setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sending %@. This email maybe sent as junk mail",fileName] isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
     }
}
```

Notice I am adding the pdf data and not the actual pdf and then I set the extension (MimeType) to pdf and then set the name of the file it is that simple to add an attachment onto an email you are constructing.

To add a link to an email it is as simple as

```
    - (void)emailFile
{
    if(![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        UIAlertView *cantSend = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Device not configured to send email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
       [cantSend show];
    } else {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailView setSubject:@"PDF Link added in HTML"];

        // Adding a HTML Link to an email. Remembering to set the Message to allow HTML.
        NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
        [mailView setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><font size=\"2\" face=\"Helvetica\"><a href=%@></br>%@</br></a></br></font></p>",link,@"Google"] isHTML:YES];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
     }
}
```

Notice that you aren't attaching any data put you are setting the `setMessage` to use HTML whereas the first example doesn't use HTML. This will now allow you to set an `NSString` in the message body that contains html elements.

**EDIT**

myPDFData is a `CFDataRef` of the dataContent of the PDF that I download from a webservice then the user can forward it to themselves via an email. If you are using `ARC` then you will need to add the bridge in `(__bridge NSData *)myPDFData` when setting attachmentData.

Hope this helps.