# Add hyperlink into preloaded text in email from ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, hyperlink

I have an iOS app with an email share button. In that, I want to include the link to our app in the app store. However, instead of just including the URL, I'd like to hyperlink it to some of the text in the body of the email. Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058447/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-how-do-i-embed-a-clickable-url-link-into-the-email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code

```
  - (void) sendEventInEmail
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setSubject:@"Email Subject"];

        // Fill out the email body text
        NSString *iTunesLink = @"--------Link to iTune App link----"; 
        NSString *content = [eventDictionary objectForKey:@"Description"];
        NSString *imageURL = [eventDictionary objectForKey:@"Image URL"];
        NSString *findOutMoreURL = [eventDictionary objectForKey:@"Link"];

        NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<br /> <a href = '%@'> <img src='%@' align=left  style='margin:5px' /> </a> <b>%@</b> <br /><br />%@ <br /><br />Sent using <a href = '%@'>What's On Reading</a> for the iPhone.</p>", findOutMoreURL, imageURL, emailSubject, content, iTunesLink];

        [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
        }

     - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
        {
            // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
            switch (result)
            {
                case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
                    break;
                case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
                    break;
                case MFMailComposeResultSent:
                    break;
                case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
```